# Calculating largest euclidean distance between two values in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance between 2 values in a 2d array. I need the largest, so I have 2 for loops to travers the arrays, and I also have a maxDistance variable to store the greatest distance as I compare.

My code looks like this

```
  //Returns the largest Euclidean distance between any two cities 
 within the cities array
 public static double furthestDistance(int[][] x)
 {
int power;
double sum = 0.0;
int distance = 0;
int maxDistance = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j<x[0].length; j++) 
  {
     sum = (x[i][j] - x[i][i+1]) + (x[i][j] - x[i][j+1]);

    power = (int) Math.pow(sum, 2);
    distance = (int)Math.sqrt(power);                     

    if (distance > maxDistance) 
    {
      maxDistance = distance;
    }



  }
}
return Math.sqrt(sum);
}
```

I am having issues, getting an error that says my arrayIndex is out of bounds, but I am not sure what the ebst way to travers my array to find the largest distance between any two values in my 2d array of around 10 "x,y coordinates"

x is an array of cities which looks like this

```
int[][] cities0 = {{22,-45},{-20,-43},{-45,29},{41,35},{21,4}, 
{23,-37},{16,-19},{-44,-10},{26,15},{6,-30},{2,35},{6,-19}};
```

I am not sure if I am approaching the problem the right way of if I am even calculating the distance properly?

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve].

Comment: If `i` and `j` go all the breadth and width of x, then `i+1` and `j+1` will get you beyond. You have both.

Answer (score 2):

The Euclidean distance is

```
public static double calculateDistance(int[] array1, int[] array2)
    {
        double Sum = 0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
           Sum = Sum + Math.pow((array1[i]-array2[i]),2.0);
        }
        return Math.sqrt(Sum);
    }
```

Now, the thing is that you have an array of points, each point is represented by a two-element array. The index out of bounds error stems from the fact that you have the line of

```
sum = (x[i][j] - x[i][i+1]) + (x[i][j] - x[i][j+1]);
```

which assumes that there is a next i and a next j, also, it assumes that the i'th element of x has at least i + 2 elements, which, if i > 0 will crash. Using the method I described at the start of my answer, your solution would look like:

```
double maxDistance = -1;
int firstPoint = -1;
int secondPoint = -1;
//notice that the limit is x.length - 1, because we will compare the penultimate
//item with the last
for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < x.length; j ++) {
        double d = calculateDistance(x[i], x[j]);
        if (d > maxDistance) {
            maxDistance = d;
            firstPoint = i;
            secondPoint = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Euclidean distance calculation was wrong in the initial code.

Also, the statement `x[i][i+1]` is problematic because you have tuples as data points and each tuple is in a different row, which means that the 
elements in the array can be accessible by either `x[i][0]`or `x[i][1]` and any value greater than 1 in the second bracket will cause an `IndexOutOfBounds` Error.
Modifying the inner loop of the code can help you :

```
for(int j = i + 1; j<x.length; j++) 
{
    sum = Math.pow((x[i][0] - x[j][0]), 2) + Math.pow((x[i][1] - x[j][1]), 2);
    distance = Math.sqrt(sum);                     
    System.out.println(distance);
    if (distance > maxDistance) 
    {
        maxDistance = distance;
    }
}
```

Since we have tuples as our coordinates, `x[i][0] - x[j][0]` denotes the difference between x-coordinates of the two points and `x[i][1] - x[j][1]` denotes the difference between y-coordinates. Using that notation, we calculate Euclidean distance. The rest is what you have wrote previously. Also change the variables to `double` rather than `int` for more precision in your calculations!
**Note**: This example is hard-coded for the input you gave in your question, you might need to modify it for using with different arrays.